# Client struct vs. implementation struct in .h file

Tags: c++, class, struct

Alright, this is basic c++ here.  I've got a class that is a Linear Linked List.  I want to declare two structs.  One of them is for the client to use (ie. the info they are going to pass into the class) and the other struct is just for me, the implementer, to manage the linked list (this is the "node").  ie:

```
//this is the one for client use
struct form {
    char *name;
    int age;
    char *address;
    //etc.
};

struct node {
    char *name; //same as in above but I am sorting the LL by this so I need it out
    form *client_form;
    node *next;
};
```

What I am confused about is exactly where to place these.  I believe it is best to place the struct that the client is going to use above the class definition, but where is the best place to put the "node" struct.  Should this go in private?  Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're asking?  Are you asking about access modifiers of variables inside the struct, or in what file you should put the definition?

Comment: *Aside*: There is no reason to duplicate `name` into `struct node`. When you sort, just reference `note_ptr->client_form->name`, for example.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about. In general I prefer to define and declare objects in the smallest possible scope. If the node is only needed by the linked list it could be a private or protected object of the linked list class ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node structure could simply be placed into your .cpp file. If there's something in your header that refers to a node, e.g. "struct node *firstNode" then you'll have to forward declare it near the top of your header, just by saying "struct node;".

So, .h:

```
struct node;
struct form {
   // form fields
};

class MyStuff {
   private:
      struct node *firstNode;
   // more Stuff
};
```

.cpp:

```
struct node {
   // node fields
};

MyStuff::MyStuff(struct form const& details) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: if I do it like that there is no way for the client to get at any of the node structures right?  I suppose as long as the "firstNode" is private all should be safe?  This has all arose because I get that wary feeling when I don't have things locked away in "private"...

Comment: That's right. Even were firstNode mistakenly public, clients still wouldn't know what the node structure itself is made of, as that's not in the header at all.